# How to create bubble plot in R using three variables

Tags: r, bubble-chart

I have 3 variables called "num_inst", "Num_products" and "num_subjects".
I want to create a bubble plot with "Num_products" as my x-axis, "num_inst" as my y-axis and the size of the bubble to be "num_subjects". A Sample of my data looks like below

```
 num_inst = c(1, 3, 5, 7) 
 num_products = c(1,5, 10, 15) 
 num_subjects = c(1000, 2500, 780, 25) 
 df = data.frame(num_inst , Num_products, num_subjects )
```

Thanks

Comment: There are many tutorials and examples if you google it. For example: https://www.sharpsightlabs.com/blog/bubble-chart-in-r-basic/

Answer (score 2):

```
gg<-ggplot(df, aes(x=num_products, y=num_inst)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col="numsubjects",size=num_subjects))   
gg
```

There are codes on the site http://r-statistics.co/Top50-Ggplot2-Visualizations-MasterList-R-Code.html#Bubble%20Plot
You should go through them for any kind of visualization you need as these are basic.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, you need to comply with the case sensitivity requirements of R, and be consistent with the same.

```
df = data.frame(num_inst, num_products, num_subjects)
```

Now, load that into some kind of bubble chart.  It's always easiest to start with something simple, and work up to more and more complex things.

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = num_inst, y = num_products, size = num_subjects)) +
        geom_point()
p
```

[image]

See the link below for more details.

http://t-redactyl.io/blog/2016/02/creating-plots-in-r-using-ggplot2-part-6-weighted-scatterplots.html